# linux mysql case insensitive lower_case_table_names=1 make server cannot be started

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I use mysql in linux ubuntu an I want to set `lower_case_table_names = 1` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. But after I inserted the variable, the mysql server cannot be started.

o

Is there any way to set `lower_case_table_names` in `my.cnf` file or an other way to set it?

I have done this before, but it was in centos and mysql server was manual started.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Config installation by download file `mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb` from mysql website (option, if you want to install mysql 8).
2. Install mysql `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.
3. Open file `my.cnf` in `/etc/mysql`, use `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`.
4. Insert the `lower_case_table_names = 1`, like bellow:

   `[mysqld]
   lower_case_table_names = 1`
5. Save file `my.cnf`.
6. Backup the folder `/etc/mysql`, like `sudo cp -r /etc/mysql /etc/mysql.bak`
7. Remove mysql installation use `sudo apt-get remove -y mysql-*` and `sudo apt-get purge -y mysql-*`.
8. copy back the folder `/etc/mysql.bak`, like `sudo cp-r /etc/mysql.bak /etc/mysql`.
9. back to step 1 and 2. In step 2, the installation will ask, if you keep the config file in folder `/etc/mysql` or use default from installation. So, I use the config file from previous installation (N).
10. Finish installation
11. check file `my.cnf`. It should be the file with `lower_case_table_names = 1`, like step 4.

After installation, mysql will read `lower_case_table_names = 1`.

Hopefully this can help.

Comment: Just as a bit of background: MySQL 8 doesn't allow changing the `lower_case` setting to differ between tables and the data dictionary. Since the latter gets created during service initialization, the proper setting needs to be configured before that happens. That's why the database is set up twice in the procedure above. On Debian-based Linux distributions, you can alternatively use apt pre-seeding to force the post-install setup script to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. The default is 0 (atleast) for Ubuntu / CentOS.
2. If you change this on an running server with databases / tables, it may corrupt the files. Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html in the paragraph "Meaning" of "0".

Since you did not post your error message, I am assuming that you already have tables with index files and to prevent the data corruption, it is safely **not** restarting.

Would have passed through if this had been set as soon as you installed the MySQL server. And when you want to change this to an existing server it is throwing the error.